# Can I reproduce the data (for research purposes) if I have a small sample of it?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I am involved into a research project and over there I have a small dataset with 35 records of data. As the size of dataset is very small, there is a risk that our machine-learning model become overfit and therefore, I need to have more data.

***I am wondering, if I can reproduce these data, given that I guess the distribution of data ?***

For example, if I guess that the distribution of the data is ***normal*** with mean=5 and std=1.3 then I simply generate 10,000 data and then I will use the reproduced data to train my machine-learning model.

I understand that, as the dataset is small, i might have more than one nominate distribution. For example, the data might be matched with Normal, Beta. Then in this case, how can i know which distribution is the best for me ?

Comment: Don't do that, don't assume distributions and generate synthetic data, this is a pointless exercise which has no bearing with your actual problem. Use the data that you do have, and if it is too little then get more data.

Comment: What do you want to finally learn with your machine-learning model?

Comment: @frank i wish to know if my reproduced-data can predict a bbinary-classification value or not ?

Comment: @Jimmy You said your data might be normal. What do you mean by "predicting a binary classification" with normal data? Are those 35 records all you have or are there additional datasets? I don't know a "Vibel" distribution, can you give me a link? If you say that your distribution could also be Beta, does it mean that you have only values between 0 and 1?  What kind of data is it, actually?

Comment: So, the target value is binary. However, I have multiple float features.

Comment: You have 35 records, each with multiple float features. And to each of those records, a binary label is attached. And you want to learn a model that predicts the label from those float features. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Jimmy How many features do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, 35 observations is not enough for ML model. You might consider more simple econometric model, for instance, logistic regression for classification problem.
However, there is one solution. I would suggest **bootstrap** (sampling from 35 observations with replacement) since bootstrap requires no assumptions about the underlying distribution and reproduces distribution from the small sample in larger one. The problem is that sample with 35 observations only might be not representative for underlying distribution of data, so bootstrapped sample might become useless.

Answer (score 0):

##### Don't do that --- it is very bad

The goal in statistical inference and prediction (including in machine learning problems) is to make a realistic inference that *includes recognition of the uncertainty that comes with having a limited amount of data*.  If you understate the inherent level of uncertainty in the inference then that is bad.  What you are proposing to do is to generate synthetic values that will overwhelm your actual data and then use this to make your inferences --- if you were to do that then all that will happen is that you will "infer" back to the assumed structure that went in to producing your synthetic data, which will generally be very different to the probabilistic structure of the actual data generating process.$^\dagger$

What you are proposing is a species of logical fallacy.  I have not heard a name for it before, but I call it the "inferential compounding fallacy".  It occures when you take a predicted outcome from a model (or simulated values from an assumed synthetic model) and then feed the outcome back in to your analysis as if it were observed data.  The effect of feeding in unbiased predictions is that you systematically underestimate the uncertainty in your inferences, and the effect of feeding in biased predictions (or synthetic data) is that you systematically bias your inference *and* underestimate the uncertainty.

---

$^\dagger$  If we were capable of guessing the probabilistic structure of data generating processes *a priori* this make the disciplines of statistics and machine learning largely moot.